# Does Calibrating The Model Affect Its Prediction Capabilities

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, unbalanced-classes, calibration, scoring-rules

Suppose, I have an imbalanced training set and train a model on it, it will be biased towards the majority class but the probability estimates would be much better calibrated as it would follow the original class distribution. Now, I try the over-sampling method SMOTE and make the model predict the minority with much better `f1-score` but the probability estimates will not as well calibrated as the previous training since we are altering the class distribution (50:50).

To remedy this, I apply the calibration step using the validation set to get the well-calibrated probability estimates. Does this calibration have to affect the model's capability of predicting the minority class which was improved using the oversampling?

Can we transform back to the actual class probability space to get accurate probability estimates without affecting the `recall/f1-score` once the model has been trained on the over-sampled training set?

Is my understanding completely wrong here?

Comment: Your `recall/f1-score` values depend on your choice of probability cutoff applied to your probability estimates. I think that many who participate on this site would emphasize a well-calibrated probability model evaluated with a [proper scoring rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_rule) first, and treating the classification decisions later based on your tradeoffs between false positives and false negatives. I don't have any experience specifically with SMOTE, however.  Please say more about what you are trying to accomplish with your modeling to help you get a more useful answer.